# Cycle thru and populate multiple DataGridViews

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I currently have a form with 6 datagridviews. I would like to go create a loop to go through and populate each of these gridviews. Currently I am using code as follows to populate 1 of the gridviews. Where dgvfurnace6 is the datagridview and ChargeInfo is a datatable I populate earlier. I know I need to nest the loop within a loop that would cycle through all of the datagridviews but how would i programmatically set the datagridview within the loop (for examples dgvfurnace5, dgvfurnace4, etc)? Thanks for any help that you can provide.

```
For i = 0 To ChargeInfo.Rows.Count - 1
       dgvfurnace6.Rows.Add()
       dgvFurnace6.Item(0, i).Value = ChargeInfo.Rows(i).Item(11)
       dgvFurnace6.Item(1, i).Value = ChargeInfo.Rows(i).Item(12)
       dgvFurnace6.Item(2, i).Value = ChargeInfo.Rows(i).Item(13)
Next
```

Comment: If the data is in a DataTable make it the DataSource.  if there are small changes between one and the other, use a DataView.  Poking data into the control is inefficient

Comment: You would need to use a collection of some kind to hold references to each of your datagridviews to iterate them. You can create one like a list, dictionary, array, etc. Or use the collection your datagridviews are presumably already in, such as your form's control's collection, groupbox, etc. I suspect you need slightly different logic to execute on each dgv though or you'd end up with ChargeInfo's data duplicated in six places...so I'm not sure I see how a loop really helps you in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I ended up adding the arrays to a list and referencing them that way.

Comment: `dgvFurnace.DataSource = ChargeInfo` is scads easier and so concise you dont need a loop.  It also has the advantage of not needlessly making copies of the data

Comment: Dgvfurnace.datasource=chargeinfo works great for 1 gridview but not 6 with slightly different data. I am repopulating the chargetable with different information for each gridview. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: That was covered in comment #1 - use DataViews